# InputText binded to a null double filed present "0.0"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

Is there a way to prevent this without creating a new converter?

```
<p:inputText value="#{myMB.myDouble}" />

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MyMB
    private Double myDouble = null;
....
```

When i enter to the view i want to see the empty input field, not with "0.0".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That can happen if you're using Tomcat 6.0.16 or newer or a fork of it using the same Apache EL parser, like JBoss AS and WebSphere AS. You basically need to tell the Apache EL parser to not coerce the primitives to their defaults by the following VM argument which is supported since Tomcat 6.0.17:

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

This problem is not related to JSF. It doesn't occur on Glassfish, for example.

Comment: @BalusC i does not work to me. I set `System.setProperty("org.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO", "false")`. I also tried vm arguments to the eclipse.

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell your server make/version. Using `System.setProperty()` only works if the EL parser hasn't been initialized at that point. Eclipse VM argument setting will only work if you start the server from within your Eclipse development environment, not in production.

Comment: @BalusC apache-tomcat-6.0.35 properly configured and started with eclipse. I put the `-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false` in "Debug Configurantion > Arguments Tab > Vm Argumentes". I have it in my pom `<dependency><groupId>javax.el</groupId><artifactId>el-pi</artifactId><version>1.0</version><scope>provided</scope></dependency>` Can it disturb the thing?

Comment: Doubleclick Tomcat server entry in Eclipse's *Servers* view. Click *Open launch configuration*. The argument should be set there.